# L2TP within local network not working

Tags: vpn, l2tp

i can't connect to my vpn server when i'm in the same network and use the external ip address to connect. It seems like the server doesn't receive any traffic. When i'm outside the network OR use the local ip of the vpn server it works.

Can someone explain that? Do you think the router is causing the problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. your router/firewall probably doesn't support hairpinning. 2. Why do you want to connect to the VPN internally? 3. If you do want to connect internally why don't you just use the internal ip address?

Comment: 1. Ok, that could be. Is there a simple way to check this? 2./3. It's just for testing purposes.

Comment: It seems that you've already tested it. You stated in your question that from the outside it works. Why do you need to test it from the inside? If you do need to test it inside then use the internal ip address.

Comment: Is there NAT somewhere ? Maybe your router doesn't accept NAT loopback

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm just wondering why it doesn't work inside. I've tested it inside the network and it didn't work. Then i found out that i works when i'm trying to connect from outside..

Comment: @Dom I don't think so because i can connect to my mail server with external ip from inside the network. If NAT loopback / hairpinning wouldn't be accepted, this wouldn't work too, would it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bypass my VPN when making requests to IPs in my local network?](http://serverfault.com/questions/827979/how-do-i-bypass-my-vpn-when-making-requests-to-ips-in-my-local-network)